# parsing a long string in c# and giving those values to parameters

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have this string in C# -

```
".... School||Abc\r\n...State||CA\r\n..."
```

The school and state are somewhere in the string. I need to parse the string in such a way that i get the values of School and State for my parameters

```
string school = abc (from String after parsing)
string state = CA (from string after parsing)
```

Comment: What is the format of the string? It is much easier to parse if it is in some sort of standardized format. Looks like it could be something like: `School||SchoolName||State||StateAbrv`

Comment: yes you're right. Except the ABC\r\nis the value. "\r\n" is after every value. So School||ABC\r\n etc..

Comment: Why does you get the string in such weird format?

Comment: Does your string contains '....'?

Comment: Does your string is in this format??? "\r\nSchool||ABC\r\nState||EEE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string longStr = "School||Abc\r\nState||CA\r\n";
string[] keyValPairs = s.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray());
Dictionary<string, string> info = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(string pair in keyValPairs)
{
   string[] split = pair.Split("||");
    //split[0] is the key, split[1] is the value
   info.Add(split[0], split[1]);
}
```

Now you can access what you need like so:

```
string school = info["School"];
string state = info["State"];
```

Where the `longStr` variable is just your long string that you start out with, not neccessarily what I set it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try split-ing string on new line chars and then it looks like a dictionary, with key values separated by ||. Another split on "||" should give you what you want.

Back of the envelope code

```
  private static void ParseMyString(string longString) {
        IEnumerable<string> shortStrings = longString.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        foreach(var ss in shortStrings) {
            var kvp = ss.Split("||".ToCharArray());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", kvp[0], kvp[1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have syntax. Cause i am pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class to parse this file, in particular if it is fixed width fields or has known delimiters.

It:

> Provides methods and properties for parsing structured text files.

Though it lives in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Text` namespace, it is a .NET assembly and can be used in all .NET projects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your string just contains values separated by `"||", "\r" or "\n"`.

string str = "School||Abc\r\n||State||CA\r\n||AA||AA";
            str = str.Trim();
            str = str.Replace("\r",string.Empty);
            str = str.Replace("\n", string.Empty);

```
        string[] keyValue = str.Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Dictionary<string, string> KeyValDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < keyValue.Length; i++,i++)
        {
            KeyValDic.Add(keyValue[i], keyValue[i + 1]);
        }
```